# Я экспортировал игру для андроид. После запуска игры Canvas выглядит не так как в редакторе

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

Я экспортировал игру для андроид. После запуска игры Canvas выглядит не так как в редакторе

Вот в телефоне[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот в редакторе[image: Без пропорции]

А вот в редакторе с пропорциями[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу найти проблему, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: У вас на телефоне обзор меньше, чем в редакторе. От этого и кнопки становятся большими. Нужно поработать с UI элементами, что бы они хорошо смотрелись на всех разрешениях. Как минимум, в Canvas Scaler установить UI Scale Mode в Scale With Screen Size. И т.д

Answer (score 1):

Ваши UI элементы растягиваются, потмоу что изменяется соотношение сторон экрана (aspect ratio).
Чтобы этого не происходило, нужно, во-впервых, при установке UI элемента использовать [anchors](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/windowsholographic-anchors.html) - якоря.
Во-вторых, как уже написали в комментариях есть такой компонент как [Canvas Scaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html). Он висит на канвасе и регулирует изменение размером UI элементов с изменением размеров экрана.
У него есть 3 возможных режима `UI Scale Mode`:

- `Contant Pixel Size` - заставляет UI элементы сохранять определенный размер в пикселях вне зависимости от размеров экрана
- `Scale With Screen Size` - делает UI элементы тем больше, чем больше размер экрана
- `Contant Physycal Size` - заставляет UI элементы сохранять определенный физический размер вне зависимости от размеров и разрешения экрана.

Если вы выберете второй режим и в `Reference Resolution` укажите то разрешение, в котором кнопки смотрятся нормально, то для других разрешений/размеров экрана они будут иметь ту же форму.

Comment: Вот у меня стояло такие параметры